# Why was the tax foreclosure question deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

It appears that https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/58581/can-i-avoid-a-tax-foreclosure-by-evading-service-of-the-summons?noredirect=1#comment120124_58581 was deleted by a moderator (community manager).  The question asked whether a person in default of property taxes could avoid having the property seized by avoiding service of process.  I spent a fair amount of time researching an answer explaining the notification requirements, referencing the relevant sections of California law, and concluding that the property would be sold anyway.  Then a few minutes later the whole question was deleted, which was frustrating.

The question was obviously based on some false premises, and the asker included some argumentative comments, but I thought the underlying legal question was clear and on-topic.

(It looks like the asker's account has been deleted.  But I thought their questions were supposed to survive account deletion?  In this case the question had a score of -4 before deletion, but there was another answer with a score of +6, and I might have thought that would be reason to preserve it.)

If this question stays deleted, I'd like to salvage my answer by posting a new question and self-answering.  However, my new question would likely be pretty similar to the original one, so I want to make sure it won't suffer the same fate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I deleted that question for the same reason as this one in [Politics](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4643/why-would-a-question-be-deleted-by-so-staff/4645#4645).

Same as there, the person who posted it is not welcome to participate on our network and should not be posting questions or answers.

The intention is to stop the harm and spending energy on a troll as fast as possible. Ultimately, I'll defer to the moderators on the site if they want to undelete and keep it around - but take that question with extreme caution and have it in mind that it was probably posted to drain time and energy from this community by generating debate.

Comment: Of some note, they posted similar q and answers on politics relating to tax disobedience leading to government collapse (possibly with some other account). Those specific q/a were deleted there by the community IIRC.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not certain, but it appears that the question was posted by someone using a new account to evade a network-wide ban.  Unfortunately the current "Destroy User" process deletes all of the user's posts ... and if the post is a question also deletes all of the answers to that question.

If there are helpful answers then I agree the question should be preserved, so if anyone sees this happen feel free to flag a moderator and we can undelete it.

([Reference Meta.SE Q&A](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312594/241697))

Comment: This isn't exactly correct: the post was deleted manually, rather than automatically as part of a user being destroyed.  You can tell by checking the timeline: it shows the name of the person who deleted it, rather than Community.  [This](https://law.stackexchange.com/posts/58614/timeline) (requires mod tools privilege) is an example of a post deleted by virtue of a user being destroyed.  Note that the deletion entry is by [Community](https://law.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community), with a comment of "User 35523 destroyed".

Comment: @RyanM You are right.  It took some digging to figure out that it was done manually by the CM as explained in the now accepted answer.